# Do I get rewards for my title rankings?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

In *Harvest Moon: A New Beginning*, when going to my Bookshelf, if I look at Picture Book > Various Data, the games shows all sorts of statistics, such as "Times Cooked", "Critters Caught", "Items Foraged", etc.

I received a popup while catching critters that I was now ranked as a Novice Catcher, which you can see below:

[image: Titles 1]

Under the categories I'm not yet ranked in, I can see that there are bronze, silver, and gold ranking levels for each title, which you can see here:

[image: Titles 2]

Will I get any sort of reward, like blueprints or seeds, for ranking up in these titles, or are these just random statistics for recordkeeping's sake? For example, there's one for "Poison Mushrooms Eaten", and I'm kind of leery of trying to rank up in that unless I really get something good for it.

Comment: Raising your Farm, Fishing (Reel), Fishing (trap), Critter catching, and Cooking degrees seems to reward multiple titles (6+), while all the other titles only reward up to three. I know that raising your Fishing (by reel or trap, they are counted separately) and Cooking Degree affects the star quality of the fish you catch and the food you cook. Raising your Farm Degree unlocks certain blueprints (e.g. Blue Furniture, Pink Furniture). Getting the gold title for poisonous mushrooms (they drain your stamina) requires eating 1000 of them.